# Shifting misaligned values to a given column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a messed up csv file with time and x and y values that I want to fix, like the one below:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4   col5     col6    col7...
Time    X       Y       X2     Y2        X3      Y3...  
1       724     82      NaN    NaN       NaN     NaN
2       717     83      NaN    NaN       NaN     NaN
3       683     81      NaN    NaN       NaN     NaN
4       NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN       NaN     NaN
5       NaN     NaN     718    78        NaN     NaN
6       NaN     NaN     710    79        NaN     NaN
7       NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN       705     83 
8       NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN       706     86
9       NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN       705     86
10      NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN       705     86
```

I want all the right shifted x and y values all in one column, analogous to selecting empty cells in excel, deleting and shifting the cells left, like so:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5     col6     col7...
Time    X       Y       X2      Y2       X3       Y3...  
1       724     82           
2       717     83           
3       683     81           
4       NaN     NaN              
5       718     78
6       710     79
7       705     83 
8       706     86
9       705     86
10      705     86
```

I would like to automate this process rather than doing it on excel, since this file spans over a hundred columns and thousands of rows.

Here are the challenges I've had so far:

1. There are NaN values that I don't want to remove (Such as the 5th row, Time = 4) and most other rows also contains NaNs. So simply removing NaN values with `df.dropna()` did not work (It also removed the values that I wanted to keep)
2. `df.shift()` also removes values that I want to keep, so simply dropping a row or column is not possible.

Any help or advice would be great.

Comment: You can use `fillna`. But as I cannot guess what are the column names of your actual dataframe, nor if Time is a true column or an index I cannot give you any code.

Comment: `df.fillna()' will only replace NaNs with whatever method you choose to fill with. What I want to do is remove the unnecessary NaNs and shift all valid values into one "X" and "Y" column.

Comment: As I have said in my previous comment, I can propose code to fill the first 2 columns and clear the other ones, provided I can build *something* with the structure of your original dataframe. Which I cannot because I need knowledge of the column names and of the indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
data = [[y for y in x if  pd.isnull(y) == False] for x in df.iloc[:,1:].values.tolist()]
new_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['X','Y'])
new_df['Time']  = df['Time']
new_df[['Time', 'X', 'Y']].dropna()
```

**Output**

```
|   | Time |   X   |  Y   |
|---|------|-------|------|
| 0 |    1 | 724.0 | 82.0 |
| 1 |    2 | 717.0 | 83.0 |
| 2 |    3 | 683.0 | 81.0 |
| 3 |    4 | NaN   | NaN  |
| 4 |    5 | 718.0 | 78.0 |
| 5 |    6 | 710.0 | 79.0 |
| 6 |    7 | 705.0 | 83.0 |
| 7 |    8 | 706.0 | 86.0 |
| 8 |    9 | 705.0 | 86.0 |
| 9 |   10 | 705.0 | 86.0 |
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this method, but I got this error:
```AssertionError: 2 columns passed, passed data had 225 columns```
Any idea where this is coming from?

Comment: So I worked on this a little bit more: 
Looking at the 'data' list, it correctly only lists the X and Y values. However, when creating the new DataFrame, ```AssertionError: 2 columns passed, passed data had 225 columns``` appears. After adding additional columns to matched the passed data, interestingly, the additional columns had 'nan' or 'None.' 

All I did after that was drop those extra columns using ```df.drop()```
Anyways, your first line of code seems to work, albeit with some tweaking. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I try create general solution with multiple non NaNs pairs per rows for convert to separate rows in final 2 columns DataFrame:

```
print (df)
col1   col2  col3   col4  col5   col6  col7
Time      X     Y     X2    Y2     X3    Y3
1     724.0  82.0    NaN   NaN    NaN   4.0 < 3 non nans values
2     717.0  83.0    NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN
3     683.0  81.0    NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN
4       NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN
5       NaN   NaN  718.0  78.0    NaN   NaN
6       NaN   NaN  710.0  79.0    NaN   NaN
7       NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN  705.0  83.0
8       NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN  706.0  86.0
9       NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN  705.0  86.0
10      NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN  705.0  86.0

#MultiIndex in df
print (df.columns)
MultiIndex(levels=[['col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7'],
                   ['X', 'X2', 'X3', 'Y', 'Y2', 'Y3']],
           codes=[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5]],
           names=['col1', 'Time'])
```

Idea is det second level of `MultiIndex` by [`MultiIndex.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html), `replace` values with no number after string and use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for 2 column `DataFrame` passed to [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html), so possible reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
a = (df.columns
       .get_level_values(1)
       .to_series()
       .replace({'X':'X1', 'Y':'Y1'})
       .str.extract('(.+)(\d+)'))
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([a[0], a[1]], names=['time','tmp'])
df1 = df.stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
print (df1)
time      X     Y
1     724.0  82.0
1       NaN   4.0
2     717.0  83.0
3     683.0  81.0
5     718.0  78.0
6     710.0  79.0
7     705.0  83.0
8     706.0  86.0
9     705.0  86.0
10    705.0  86.0
```

But all only NaNs rows are removed, so first get this index values by [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html), pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index.difference(df1.index))
print (df2)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [4]
```

And use [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) for add them to original, because `reindex` not working with duplicates values:

```
df3 = df1.append(df2, sort=True).sort_index()
print (df3)
        X     Y
1   724.0  82.0
1     NaN   4.0
2   717.0  83.0
3   683.0  81.0
4     NaN   NaN
5   718.0  78.0
6   710.0  79.0
7   705.0  83.0
8   706.0  86.0
9   705.0  86.0
10  705.0  86.0
```

Comment: Is there a way to set the levels of the multiIndex automatically? Because there are 255 columns in the actual file.

Comment: @EricO - What is `print(df.columns)` ? Because if not MultiIndex maybe need `df = pd.read_csv(file, header=[0,1])`

Answer (score 0):

`set_index` column `Time`. Using numpy `argmax` to find 1st position of non-`NaN` of each row. Construct 2d array `n` from the `a` array result of `argmax`. Using fance index to generate 2d array of non-`NaN` from `df.values` and use it to create new dataframe

```
df = df.set_index('Time')
a = df.isna().values.argmax(1)
n = np.column_stack([a, a+1])

In [447]: a
Out[447]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4], dtype=int64)

In [449]: n
Out[449]:
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [4, 5],
       [4, 5],
       [4, 5]], dtype=int64)
```

Fancy Index:

```
df.values[np.arange(len(df))[:,None], n]

Out[450]:
array([[724.,  82.],
       [717.,  83.],
       [683.,  81.],
       [ nan,  nan],
       [718.,  78.],
       [710.,  79.],
       [705.,  83.],
       [706.,  86.],
       [705.,  86.],
       [705.,  86.]])
```

Construct new dataframe from result of fancy index:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values[np.arange(len(df))[:,None], n], columns=['X', 'Y'])

Out[452]:
       X     Y
0  724.0  82.0
1  717.0  83.0
2  683.0  81.0
3    NaN   NaN
4  718.0  78.0
5  710.0  79.0
6  705.0  83.0
7  706.0  86.0
8  705.0  86.0
9  705.0  86.0
```

Comment: I gave yours a shot, but for some reason the resulting dataframe was empty, plus the Fancy Index did not alter the data frame in anyway. I found out that some of my NA values were empty strings (which would affect ```df.isna()```) but when reading the CSV data, I specified the empty string as a NA value. 
Anything I should diagnose?